# reading tab delimited text file in julia using python library (Pandas)

Tags: pandas, julia

i tried this line of code to read a text file with julia

```
using Pandas
data= pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/WEJDENE/Desktop/clinical_tcga.txt", '\t')
```

However i got this error :

```
PyError ($(Expr(:escape, :(ccall(#= C:\Users\WEJDENE\.julia\packages\PyCall\zqDXB\src\pyfncall.jl:43 =# @pysym(:PyObject_Call), PyPtr, (PyPtr, PyPtr, PyPtr), o, pyargsptr, kw))))) <class 'TypeError'>
TypeError("object of type 'PyCall.jlwrap' has no len()")
  File "C:\Users\WEJDENE\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\WEJDENE\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\WEJDENE\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 875, in __init__
    self.options, self.engine = self._clean_options(options, engine)
  File "C:\Users\WEJDENE\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 962, in _clean_options
    elif sep is not None and len(sep) > 1:
```

Comment: is that how you imported pandas? or with import pandas

Comment: i'm using julia not python so i've imported the package pandas by typing ` using PyCall; import Pkg; Pkg.add("PyCall"); pandas = pyimport("pandas") `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, because you are using the `pandas` library from Python, you do not need to run the `using Pandas` statement as that refers to [this](https://github.com/JuliaPy/Pandas.jl) Julia package.

Also, make sure that you have run the following code to add the Python `pandas` library to the Julia version of Python.

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("PyCall")

using Conda
Conda.add("pandas") # Add the pandas library to the Conda environment if you have not already
```

I was able to reproduce your error, and I noticed that you had passed `'\t'` as a parameter to the `pandas.read_csv` function call. In Julia, the `''` symbol denotes a character data type, and when the PyCall library sees more than one character wrapped inside the single quotes, it throws an error.

To fix this, changing the `'\t'` to a `"\t"` fixed the problem because the parameter is a string. I have put the code below to do this.

```
using PyCall
pandas = pyimport("pandas")
data = pandas.read_csv("filepath.txt", "\t")
```